# Sound not playing in Phonegap app after changing to 3.1.0

Tags: ios, audio, mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap app that plays sound when you click and icon. It worked fine before I upgraded my phonegap build version from 2.9.0 to 3.1.0 (ios 7 build support).

Here is my code

```
        //Play Audio
        function playAudio(src) {
            if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
            }                
            var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);   
            // Set Volume
            media.setVolume('0.7');
            media.play();

        }

        function success() {
            // Default the icon
            $('#sound-icon').removeClass('sound-icon-active').addClass('sound-icon-default');
            //Ga tracking
            ga_storage._trackEvent('Sound Played', 'Play', 'Sound Played succesfully.');

        }
```

The code mysteriously stopped working. Could i be missing something here or is there something that changed in the iOS SDK

EDIT : I resolved the issue according to input from  Dawson Loudon , in phonegap 3.x you have to include different plugins to access device specific features. In my case I needed to add the following:

to the config.xml.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: In 3.x all device specific functions have been broken out into separate plugins. Have you added the media plugin to your app?

Comment: What media plugin do i have to include and can the above code still be valid??

Comment: The code should still be valid. Are you using build.phonegap.com or building locally?

Comment: I am using phonegap build

Comment: I have included the plugin : <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" /> and its still not working. :(

Comment: Just a thought, have you added the `device` plugin as well? The code above will fail when trying `if(device.plaform == 'Android')` if not.

Comment: Adding the device plugin worked....Thanks Dawson Loudon :)

Comment: Great! Going to add an answer for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving from PhoneGap 2.x to 3.x the biggest change is that all of the APIs are broken into separate plugins. This means that any device specific API needs to be installed as a plugin.

Looking at your code, you will need the `device` and `media` plugins installed.

For PhoneGap Build add this to `config.xml`:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.8" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.8" />
```

For CLI run these commands (and rebuild or prepare):

```
(sudo) cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
(sudo) cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```