# Cordova / Phonegap Media no sound on iOS IPhone 6 device

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins

I'm using the cordova media plugin and trying to play a simple .wav file.  I am using the example code as in the git, and it works in the iOS simulator.  However, when I run it on the device (IPhone 6, iOS 8.3), no sounds play.  I am getting the following from the log:

2015-06-24 21:19:21.310 myapp[670:143925] Found resource '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/59CEEB50-4603-4AFD-8CF8-CD083ADE6FA4/myapp.app/www/audio/bell.wav' in the web folder.
2015-06-24 21:19:21.340 myapp[670:143925] Playing audio sample 'audio/bell.wav'
2015-06-24 21:19:25.317 myapp[670:143925] Finished playing audio sample 'audio/bell.wav'
2015-06-24 21:19:25.321 myapp[670:143925] audiosuccess
2015-06-24 21:19:25.322 myapp[670:143925] Media with id d627afe1-fe1c-6524-2479-94bf72dc2f01 released

So it seems that the file was found and played.  But no sound is heard?  I am not sure if there are some settings i need to preset for the device to work or if this is a bug with it.

Comment: can you check your phonegap version, from version 3.1.0 onwards audio is not playing, it has been discussed in the stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669724/sound-not-playing-in-phonegap-app-after-changing-to-3-1-0

Comment: didi you actually solve this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

A possible gotcha that has "got me" before:

Are you certain that the sound is fully switched on?
You must have the volume set, but there is also a switch beside the volume buttons on iPhones/iPads which allows completely disabling the volume (it shows orange when off) -- it's easy to forget this is switched off because it doesn't actually disable all audio on the device (for example video's will ignore it and still play with audio, but playing an audio file will honour it and not make any sound)

Comment: Yes the switch is for volume on.  That's not the problem, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you are right! There is a switch beside the volume buttons. I just turn it on and sound works, Thank you!